# Parsing multiple xlsx files with some data manipulation to create a new file

Tags: python

I want to parse multiple .xlsx files reading only a specific sheet name "Target" (filename format : "name_20190626.xlsx" with the version date in the filename), extract the version date from filename, add this date i.e. 20190626 as a new column for every row in each file and create a data frame with selected columns [Col 0,1,-1] from all the .xlsx files.

I managed to open the right sheet, extract the date and load the columns I want, it's when I try to add the new column that I get an error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("01_Historical_files/*.xlsx"):
    print(f)
    """ df = pd.read_excel(f)  """
    date = re.findall("(\d{8})", f)
    print(date)
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    df = xl.parse('STATIC').iloc[:,[0,1,-1]]
    df.assign(score_date = date)
    df.head()
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Expected output (with all rows):

- Column 1 containing the version date for all rows of the same file
- Column 2 containing the "deduplication factor" - would be great if I can filter values equal to 1 in the dataframe already.
- Column 3 a unique ID
- Column 4 the last column containing a score

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to make it work - Still open for better ways of doing it ;)

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("01_Historical_files/*.xlsx"):
    print(f)
    """ df = pd.read_excel(f)  """


    xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)

    date2 = xl.parse('SOURCES >>>').iloc[1,1]
    print(date2)
    df = xl.parse('STATIC').iloc[:,[0,1,-1]]


    """ Looping across all rows within the df frame """
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
      """print (i)   """ 
      df['score_date'] = date2

    df.head()

    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```